VF page not loading when I updated the API version
Our project is updating all the Pages/Components which are below API version 30 and as part of which I have updated the SOAP API version of an existing VF page from 29.0 to 56.0. But while testing I could see that the VF page is not loading.
Old value:
<script src="../../soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Updated value:
<script src="../../soap/ajax/56.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

I looked at the code and could see on the initial load they are trying to get layout value using below code:
var result = sforce.connection.describeLayout('Contact_Relationship__c', new Array('{!ContactRelRecordType}'));

For above line, with 29.0 I'm getting proper response but for 56.0 I'm getting undefined.

And in the Catch I'm seeing below error:

Is there any syntax change to get the layout into the VF page for new version?

We need more code than what you've shown here. Please [edit] your question to include the surrounding code.

I am able to fix this issue. The describeLayout() in 29.0 version is expecting 2 arguments, but in the latest versions it is expecting 3 arguments:
NEW:
sforce.Connection.prototype.describeLayout = function(type, layoutName, recordTypes, callback) {

    var arg1 = new sforce.internal.Parameter("sObjectType", type, false);
    if (!layoutName) {
        layoutName = null;
    }
    

    var arg2 = new sforce.internal.Parameter("layoutName", layoutName, false);
    if (!recordTypes) {
        recordTypes = [];
    }


    var arg3 = new sforce.internal.Parameter("recordTypeIds", recordTypes, true);
    return this.invoke("describeLayout", [arg1, arg2, arg3], false, callback);
};


OLD:
sforce.Connection.prototype.describeLayout = function(type, recordTypes, callback) {
    var arg1 = new sforce.internal.Parameter("sObjectType", type, false);
    if (!recordTypes) {
        recordTypes = [];
    }

    var arg2 = new sforce.internal.Parameter("recordTypeIds", recordTypes, true);
    return this.invoke("describeLayout", [arg1, arg2], false, callback);
};

Passed a null argument as 3rd parameter to my existing call and it worked.
